# How to get text rows of equal size in text box while reading data from serialport?

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I read data from serial port in textbox, then I save it in a textfile.

1. when I use `RxString = serialPort1.ReadLine();` I get Textrows of uneven   size in textbox, and even sized Textrows in the saved textfile.
2. when I use `RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();` I get Textrows of even size in textbox and uneven sized Textrows in the saved textfile.
3. My code looks like this:

   ```
   private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
   {
        RxString = serialPort1.ReadLine();
       // RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
       this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));

    }
   ```

My data should look like:

```
 150101 02:30:30,7 0030;0000;00;00;00;00;0000;0000;80;10;E008 

 150101 02:30:30,8 0030;0000;00;00;00;00;0000;0000;00;10;E008

 150101 02:30:30,7 0030;0000;00;00;00;00;0000;0000;80;10;E008 

 150101 02:30:30,8 0030;0000;00;00;00;00;0000;0000;00;10;E008
```

and not Like this:

```
 150101 03:06:32,8 0030;0000;00;00;00;00;0000;

   0000;80;10;E008150101 03:06:32,9 

  0030;0000;00;00;00;00;0000;0000;00;10;E008

  150101 03:06:32,0 0030;0000;00;00;00;00;0000;0000;   
                     00;10;E008150101 03:06:33,1 

  0030;0000;00;00;00;00;0000;0000;00;10;E008
```

I hope someone will understand my problem and help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ReadTo()` method

See [MSDN description here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> This method reads a string up to the specified value. While the
>   returned string does not include the value, the value is removed from
>   the input buffer.

This should be also:

```
RxString = serialPort1.ReadTo("E008");
```

It sometimes happens when the data are send rather quickly to SerialPort, also you can try to set [SerialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.receivedbytesthreshold%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), if the lenght of the string is allways the same.

```
serialPort1.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 62;
```